# Jframe Splash screen wont display an image

Tags: java, swing, jframe, splash-screen

I cant seem to add an image to the JFRAME when run, it opens the Splash screen and displays the loading bar and the text, but no image, the image is in the same location as the code. The image path is fine as none needed and when hovered over, it displays the image in my IDE, Any assistance would be amazing.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SplashScreen {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SplashScreen();
    new MenuGui();
}
JFrame f;
JLabel image = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Calc.png"));
JLabel text = new JLabel("Loading...");
JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
JLabel message = new JLabel();


SplashScreen() {
    CreateGui();
    addImage();
    addText();
    addProgressBar();
    addMessage();
    runningPBar();
    f.add(image);
    f.add(progressBar);
    f.add(message);
    f.add(text);

}

public void CreateGui() {
    f = new JFrame();
    f.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    f.setUndecorated(true);
    f.setSize(600, 600);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    f.setVisible(true);
   
}
public void addText(){
    text.setFont(new Font("arial",Font.BOLD,30));
    text.setBounds(170,220,600,40);
    text.setForeground(Color.black);
    f.add(text);
}

public void addImage(){
    image.setBounds(20,30,200,300);
    image.setSize(600,200);

}

public void addMessage(){
    message.setBounds(100, 280, 400, 30);
    message.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    message.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 15));
    f.add(message);
}
public void addProgressBar(){
    progressBar.setBounds(100,280,400,30);
    progressBar.setBorderPainted(true);
    progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
    progressBar.setForeground(Color.black);
    progressBar.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    progressBar.setValue(0);
    f.add(progressBar);
}
public void runningPBar(){
    int i = 0;

    while (i <=100){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
            progressBar.setValue(i);
            message.setText("LOADING" + Integer.toString(i) + "%");
            i++;
            if(i == 100)
                f.dispose();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: class.java (source) files are sometimes kept in a different directory than class.class (object) files.  You do no error checking when you read the Calc.png file.  Create a resource folder for your project and put your images in the resource folder.  Oracle has a tutorial, [How to Create a Splash Screen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html).

Comment: Where in you code do you do `f.add(image)`?  I'd also highly discourage the use of `null` layouts, of, and `runningBar` has the potential of blocking the Event Dispatching Thread which would make it appear as your UI has "hung" and will be non responsive and add to the mix that Swing is not thread safe and you have another issue to deal with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the immediate issue I can see is the fact that you don't actually add `image` to your frame.

You also need to beware of the limitations of `ImageIcon`.  In your case, it's expecting to find a image named `Calc.png` within the current working directory, the problem with that is, the working directory can change.

A better solution is to "embed" these resources.  How this is done typically comes down to the IDE and build system your are using, but the intention is that the image will end up within the class path of the running app, typically included in the JAR.

But there are a litany of other issues which aren't going to help you.

Swing is not thread safe and is single threaded.  This means you shouldn't update the UI (or any state the UI relies on) from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread and you shouldn't perform any long running operations from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread either.

See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details.

This leaves you with a problem.  How do you do work, without blocking the UI, and keep the the UI up-to-date?  Well, see [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for the most common solution.

While you can use Java's inbuilt splash screen support, see [How to Create a Splash Screen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) for more details, I tend to avoid it (personally).  While it is most certainly faster, it's also ... clunky (IMHO)

Personally, I like to make use of undecorated window and just do what I need to do, for example...

[image: Loading Sith OS]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.color.ColorSpace;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ColorConvertOp;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.setUndecorated(true);
                    SplashPane splashPane = new SplashPane();
                    splashPane.setSplashListener(new SplashListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void didCompleteLoading(SplashPane source) {
                            frame.dispose();
                        }
                    });
                    frame.add(splashPane);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public interface SplashListener {
        public void didCompleteLoading(SplashPane source);
    }

    public class SplashPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage coloredImage;
        private BufferedImage grayscaleImage;

        private JLabel loadingLabel;
        private JLabel tagLine;

        private LoadingWorker loadingWorker;

        private double progress = 0;

        private SplashListener splashListener;

        public SplashPane() throws IOException {
            coloredImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/SplashScreen.jpeg"));
            ColorConvertOp op = new ColorConvertOp(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY), null);
            grayscaleImage = op.filter(coloredImage, null);

            loadingLabel = new JLabel("Loading Sith OS");
            tagLine = new JLabel("Your lack of faith is disturbing");

            Font font = loadingLabel.getFont();
            Font extraLargeFont = font.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, font.getSize() * 4);
            Font largeFont = font.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, font.getSize() * 2);

            loadingLabel.setFont(extraLargeFont);
            loadingLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

            tagLine.setFont(largeFont);
            tagLine.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20);
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 0.5;

            add(loadingLabel, gbc);

            gbc.gridy = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
            add(tagLine, gbc);

            configureLoadingWorker();
        }

        public void setSplashListener(SplashListener listener) {
            splashListener = listener;
        }

        protected void configureLoadingWorker() {
            loadingWorker = new LoadingWorker();
            loadingWorker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                    if (loadingWorker.getState() == SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE) {
                        progress = 1.0;
                        repaint();
                        // Because it's nice to see that last little bit of progress
                        Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                if (splashListener != null) {
                                    splashListener.didCompleteLoading(SplashPane.this);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        timer.setRepeats(false);
                        timer.start();
                    } else if ("progress".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                        progress = loadingWorker.getProgress() / 100.0;
                        repaint();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify();
            loadingWorker.execute();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeNotify() {
            super.removeNotify();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(coloredImage.getWidth(), coloredImage.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int xPos = (getWidth() - coloredImage.getWidth()) / 2;
            int yPos = (getHeight() - coloredImage.getHeight()) / 2;
            g2d.drawImage(grayscaleImage, xPos, yPos, this);

            int targetHeight = (int) (coloredImage.getHeight() * progress);
            if (targetHeight > 0) {
                BufferedImage subimage = coloredImage.getSubimage(0, coloredImage.getHeight() - targetHeight, coloredImage.getWidth(), targetHeight);
                xPos = (getWidth() - coloredImage.getWidth()) / 2;
                yPos = ((getHeight() - coloredImage.getHeight()) / 2) + (coloredImage.getHeight() - targetHeight);
                g2d.drawImage(subimage, xPos, yPos, this);
            }

            g2d.dispose();
        }

        protected class LoadingWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int progress = 0;
                Thread.sleep(2);
                do {
                    int delta = rnd.nextInt(9) + 1;
                    progress += delta;
                    setProgress(progress);
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } while (progress < 100);
                setProgress(100);
                return null;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, all solved!

Comment: the image is added with f.image - this was in the original code SplashScreen() {
    CreateGui();
    addImage();
    addText();
    addProgressBar();
    addMessage();
    runningPBar();
    f.add(image);
    f.add(progressBar);
    f.add(message);
    f.add(text);

}